# How do access the HttpServerUtility in a WebAPI controller (MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext

I need to access the Server.MapPath(virtualPath) method in a controller in an MVC 4  ApiController.

The answer is usually to access it from ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.  However, unlike MvcControllers, the ControlerContext for an ApiController has no HttpContext.

The WebApiAppication that is instantiated in Global.asax.cs has an HttpContext element (Context).  However, unlike MVC 3 and earlier, I can't find a way to access the WebApiApplication from a controller. (Earlier generations stored a reference to it in a static Instance variable. MVC 4 removes that.)

Also, I'm trying to find something that will also work without a ton of extra scaffolding when I call the controller methods from a unit Test. I think I could access it, even in a WebApi Controller, using HttpContext.Current (at least it compiles), but I can't mock that for testing. (I'm talking unit testing here, where you call directly to the Controller methods.  I've seen some recent tutorials where you unit test with a thin HttpClient, and thus test the whole stack.  That seems more like low-level integration testing to me.)

This doesn't seem like it should be that difficult, but I've spent several hours googling it and trying things, and my head's getting bloody from beating it against the wall.

Comment: Possible soution is you can wrap `ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server` to another class for testing, why not?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you abstracting this functionality:

```
public interface IMyDependency
{
    string MapPath(string path);
}
```

and then have an implementation:

```
public class MyConcreteDependency: IMyDependency
{
    public string MapPath(string path)
    {
        return HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);
    }
}
```

and finally your ApiController is completely independent on all static method calls making it unit test friendly:

```
public class MyController: ApiController
{
    private readonly IMyDependency dependency;
    public MyController(IMyDependency dependency)
    {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var path = this.dependency.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `ApiControllers`, build yourself a `DelegatingHandler` and push all of your goodies onto `request.Properties`. You can then retrieve them from your request whether you are testing or running live. The benefit is that you then have zero dependency on Session in your Controller.

### MessageHandler

```
public class ContextHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // get the goodies to add onto the request
        var goodies = /* call to goodieGoodieYumYum */


        // add our goodies onto the request
        request.Properties.Add(Constants.RequestKey_Goodies, goodies);

        // pass along to the next handler
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

### Controller Action

```
var goodies = (List<Goodie>)Request.Properties[Constants.RequestKey_Goodies];
```